# Localizations and their underlying groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Fix $\mathcal C$ an $\infty$-category and $W \subset \mathcal C$ the inclusion of an $\infty$-category containing all weak equivalences in $\mathcal C$.

The localization along $W$ is then (a Joyal-fibrant replacement for) the pushout $|W| \leftarrow W \to \mathcal C$.

Is there a proof that the underlying $\infty$-groupoid of the localization $\mathcal C [W^{-1}]$ is naturally equivalent to $|W|$? (Here, $|W|$ is the Kan-fibrant replacement of $W$.) Put another way, the largest subcategory of the localization containing only equivalences seems equivalent to the groupoid-ification of $W$. What's a proof?

I mean "naturally" in the technical sense---the equivalence should be a natural transformation for the $\infty$-category of pairs $(\mathcal C, W)$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true without further assumptions on $W$ (e.g. the 2-out-of-3 property or the 2-out-of-6 property). You could probably find relevant stuff in the Barwick-Kan papers on relative categories.